# Share one User Table with two Drupal Sites

Tags: users, multi-sites

I have a drupal site which has thousands registered users. (I also added fields like age,dob country etc at /admin/config/people/accounts/fields)

I have another site which is hosted at the same hosting with different database.

Is there a way that i can use first site USERS table in the second site ? 
(user registration, forget password and login etc will be connected to first site)

Any clue?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe this module does what you need [Domain Access](https://drupal.org/project/domain)